# Как работает функция read() в потоке чтения символов?

Tags: java, io

```
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    char res = ' ';
    do {
        try {
            res = (char)bf.read();
            System.out.println(res);
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
    } while (res != 'q');
```

Как я понимаю, функция read() считывает 1 символ, но при запуске программы я могу ввести несколько символов, а потом цикл по очереди все их выводит. Почему так происходит? Например, я введу строку "abc" это строчка `res = (char)bf.read();` она должна(как мне кажется) взять только первый символ, а потом должна выполняться строчка `System.out.println(res);`, которая должна вывести этот первый символ, но получается, что функция read() собирает все символы, а потом их выводит. Можете, пожалуйста объяснить что и как происходит внутри функции read().

Comment: Так происходит потому, что вы завернули `InputStreamReader` в `BufferedReader`. Зачем вы это сделали?

Comment: Чтобы считывать символы с клавиатуры.

Comment: Можете объяснить, пожалуйста, что происходит в этой программе по шагово, а то я не очень понимаю.

Comment: Для считывания `InputStreamReader` достаточно. Почитайте описание класса `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Да, я это знаю. Но суть вопроса не в этом. Я не понимаю как работает  read().

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` сначала считывает в буфер строку из `InputStreamReader`, а потом из буфера отдаёт по одному символу методу `read`, при каждом его вызове.

Comment: Такой же код без буфера будет работать также.

Comment: `char c = ' ';
  InputStreamReader a = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

  while (c != 'q') {
   try {
    c = (char)a.read();
    System.out.println(c);
   } catch (IOException ex) {}
  }`

Comment: @SanekHoma у большинства терминалов есть ещё и свой собственный буфер, который они не отдадут программе до тех пор, пока пользователь не нажмёт клавишу ввода. Если вам нужно читать по одному символу, используйте [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).